# How can i delete specific sub-directories google cloud storage python SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I have the following code :

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage.Bucket(storage_client, name="mybucket")
blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_or_name=bucket, prefix="content/")
print('Blobs:')
for blob in blobs:
   print(blob.name)
```

My storage hierarchy is :

- "content/{uid}/subContentDirectory1/anyFiles*"
- "content/{uid}/subContentDirectory2/anyFiles*"

My goal is to be able to delete from the python code `content/{uid}/subContentDirectory1`

With the above code, i am retrieving all the files in all sub-directories of `content` but i don't know how to wildcard to delete only a specific subdirectory.

I am aware i can do it with `gsutil` but it will be running in an AWS lambda function so i would rather use the python SDK.

How can i do that ?

EDIT : to make it more clear, the `{uid}` is the wildcard, that can possibly match millions of results and under each of these result, i want to delete `subContentDirectory1`.